# What does "dark in the pocket" mean

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

I've read a short story by F. Scott Fitzgerald called [Afternoon of an Author](http://www.gutenberg.net.au/fsf/AFTERNOON-OF-AN-AUTHOR.html).

There is a phrase I don't understand at all:

> He passed a sporting goods store and looked in the window unmoved except by a first baseman's glove which was already **dark in the pocket**.

What does "dark in the pocket" mean in this context? By searching I only learned that "pocket" is the part of the baseball glove, but the phrase still doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't mean anything non-literal - a baseball glove which has been heavily used will typically develop a dark spot in the pocket as the dirt transfers from the ball to the glove.

[image: baseball glove]